# Programatically fill Government PDF (XFA dynamic)

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, xfa

I need to fill a form from a XFA PDF generated with LiveCycle. I'm using PDFBox 3.0.0-beta1 atm and I've tried iText 4.2.0 and PDFBox 2.0.28 but with no success. Anything I do to the PDF, results in a unusable PDF, it breaks the usage rights if I understood correctly. Below is my java code:

```
PDDocument doc = Loader.loadPDF(new File(Paths.get(FileUtils.listFiles(new File("formulare"), new PrefixFileFilter("F1129"), null).toArray()[0].toString()).toUri()));
PDDocumentCatalog catalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = catalog.getAcroForm();
PDXFAResource xfa1 = acroForm.getXFA();

COSStream cosout = doc.getDocument().createCOSStream();
OutputStream out = cosout.createRawOutputStream();

TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();

StreamResult result = new StreamResult(out);
Document src2 = acroForm.getXFA().getDocument();

NodeList dataElements = src2.getElementsByTagName("script");
if (dataElements != null) {
  for (int i = 0; i < dataElements.getLength(); i++) {
    if (i == 45) {                   
       dataElements.item(i).setTextContent(dataElements.item(i).getTextContent() + "csDataTool.GetInstance().ExecuteImport();");
    }
  }
}

transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(src2), result);

PDXFAResource xfaout = new PDXFAResource(cosout);
acroForm.setXFA(xfaout);
out.close();

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("f1129Modified.pdf");
doc.saveIncremental(fos);
doc.close();
cosout.close();
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

i == 45 (that is the position of the script I want to edit)

But after I modify the XFA, the PDF opens normally but I can't to anything in it. No errors, no warnings... but if I just do this

```
dataElements.item(i).setTextContent(dataElements.item(i).getTextContent());
```

it works perfectly...

My question is: is this even possible? To modify the javascript without breaking usage rights? If not, how can I fill this PDF?
The XML that they want to be attached has different tags than the XSD I've tried to find inside the XFA.

The PDF in question can be downloaded from here: https://mfinante.gov.ro/documents/2552173/2552377/31.OrdinPlataElectronic_2023_05_19_A2.0.26+.pdf/5acf3ff7-7ff1-aa2c-283c-151d49af0d8b?t=1684492636871&download=true

An example of a XML to be imported:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<f1129 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="mfp:anaf:dgti:f1129:declaratie:v1" xmlns="mfp:anaf:dgti:f1129:declaratie:v1" versiune_pdf="A2.0.21" d_rec="0" suma_control="3644129" total_opm="245.5" nr_inregistrari="1" luna_r="12" an="2022" data_document="19.12.2022" nr_document="1234567890" nume_ip="asdasdas" adresa_ip="asddas" cui_ip="3643884" tip_ent="1">
  <rand_op nr_op="32" iban_platitor="RO38TREZ24A670503200109X" den_trezorerie="TREZORERIA  STATULUI" cod_program="0000000000" cod_angajament="AAAFSF23N4X" ind_angajament="AA2" cui_beneficiar="17460640" den_beneficiar="Your Consulting SRL" iban_beneficiar="RO38TREZ24A670503200109X" den_banca_trez="TREZORERIA  STATULUI" suma_op="245.5" explicatii="asdasd" />
</f1129>
```

The strangest thing is that if I use Adobe Reader PRO everything works fine. xD And I can't find a reason why ...

Comment: The PDF contains a usage rights signature (UR3) which breaks when you edit it. Did you try to do your changes in append mode? In PDF 2.0 usage rights signatures are deprecated, so if you ask the document owner you might be able to remove it?

Comment: Yeah, I've have tried with append mode and still no success... and I can't contact the owner sadly ...

Comment: I've tried to remove it with LiveCycle but it becomes unusable ... is there another method?

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'UR3' same for UR ... i'm using pdfbox  2.0.28 and 3.0.0-alpha3, and only using document.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true); results in an unusable PDF ...

Comment: The code was untestet  and was to show how it could be done. Here is a corrected version:
`PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
document.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true); 
COSDictionary dictionary = document.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject(); 
dictionary.removeItem(COSName.PERMS); 
dictionary.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
...`

Comment: Still the PDF is unusable ... but thank you for trying ...

Comment: What do you mean by not usable? Did you try to remove it, save it? The the size should be 62-63 KB. Then load this file and do your changes... If that doesn't help then post your result file and we can take a look. Maybe the things you do break the PDF in another way...

Comment: Idk if you opened the PDF but if you did, I just want to call the "Import XML" function when opening the PDF. So I have just added a call for a function inside of an existing event.

<event activity="initialize" name="event__initialize">
<script contentType="application/x-javascript">
 csDataTool.GetInstance().ExecuteImport();
</script>
</event>

Comment: [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6f739245ace02d9a64f28357df273a2420230726121620/1aaa3d) This is the final PDF that I got...

Comment: Ok your are doing much more than written here: The original file is 70kb and if I remove the UR-Signature the file is 63kb. Your file is 115kb. The producer also says "modified using OpenPDf 1.3.30" - here you only write about Pdfbox. I can see 2 additions using append mode. But removing a UR-Signature should not be done in append mode. Also adobe reports lots of errors. So something breaks along the line of what your are doing...

Comment: Sorry I've uploaded the wrong PDF. Indeed the modified PDF has 63kb but I can't use the "Import XML".
[link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1694c638483056ee7d53c9b54ad7b0ae20230727065111/c65da5)

After the removal of the signature I try to modify the javascript behind the PDF to use the "Import XML" function when the PDF is opened and I attach a XML file. That's why the other one was 113kb. I've tried PDFBox, iText 4 and now OpenPDF 1.3.30...
The point is that I need to fill the form and send it back to the government.

Comment: If I click on the "import XML" Button it is working for me - I successfully added the xml as an attachment. Update: You have written: "if I use Adobe Reader PRO everything works fine" - that explains it. One reason could be if you remove the usage rights then you are not able to use certain features of adobe reader (anymore) which are normally reserved for acrobat pro version

Comment: Well that makes alot of sense...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is not completely clear what you want*, here are some answers to part of your questions:

> My question is: is this even possible? To modify the javascript
> without breaking usage rights?

It is a signature so no. If you manipulate the document you'll break the signature. In the past there was a mechanism called "reader enabled" where you could unlock features in _dobe reader for certain documents. It might be that the document was "reader enabled" and thus allows editing XFA forms in _dobe reader. Found the following infos as part of the signature:

```
appRightsDocument: FullSave
appRightsForm: FillIn,Add,Delete
appRightsSignature: Modify
appRightsAnnots: 
appRightsEF: Create,Delete,Modify,Import
```

So to change the JavaScript you have to remove the UA-signature but then you might loose the rights to do stuff in _dobe reader.

**And finally one remark about XFA: XFA is a proprietary standard of adobe and has been deprecated in PDF2.0. I would not use it for any project (ever).**

---

*

- Why do you want to change the javascript - what is not working for you?
- To what JavaScript do you want to change the existing value?
- You said that _dobe acrobat pro is working - so you have a working solution?

Comment: I need to fill this form programatically, flatten it, sign it (digital signature) and send it to the owner. The only idea I had was to use that function "Import XML" inside the PDF, but that function works only when the button is pressed so I wanted to change the behavior and use the function when the PDF is opened. Now I get it that it's impossible to change the code inside the PDF because of their signature...

Comment: as mentioned: you can remove it (thus change it) but then you might loose the "benefits" which come with it...

Comment: Yeah I understand now. I will try to find another way... I did succeed in filling it with xfa:data but now I need to flatten it so I can sign it. The problem is when I try to flatten it I get a PDF with only one page with "Please wait ..." xD I think that what I wanna accomplish is impossible

Comment: Part of the problem is that you are (the document) using XFA - if the document would use acro forms then your requirements would be no problem...

Comment: Yeah I know but that's my ancient government xD. Thank you very much for your help!